# Entity Framework creating unwanted column

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-interface

I have a project class which contains:

```
int ProjectID;
string ProjectName;
List<Item> Items;
```

I have a item class which contains:

```
int ItemID;
int? ParentID; // ID of Parent Item
string ItemName;
List<Item> Items;
```

I would expect my Items Table to hold the following columns:
`ItemID, ParentID, ItemName`

But for some reason it's adding another column `ItemItemID`.

I have tried several things with fluent API. (WithOptional, MapKey etc...) But I can't find a thing that is working for me. I think the problem is that the `ParentID` is not seen as the relation for the Item.

Please show me a solution, cause I'm already stuck for hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework could not infer that the `ParentID` property is actually the foreign key to the parent `Item` object in the same table, so it decided to create a special column for that in the database. You have to tell it that `ParentID` is actually a foreign key by using the [ForeignKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

Change the definition of the `Item` class to something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentID { get; set; } // ID of Parent Item
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Notice how I added a `public virtual Item Parent` property because the `ForeignKey` attribute needs to point to the property that presents the parent entity.

If you prefer to use the fluent API, then remove the ForeignKey attribute, and override the `OnModelCreating` method on the context class to something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Item>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Items)
        .WithOptional(e => e.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yacoub! I have implemented your fluent API example and added the public virtual Item Parent {get; set;} to the Item class. This has the desired result.